# Centralized configuration management as a microservice in service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Just wondering if anybody out there has thought/implemented a configuration system as a microservice itself.  I thought that it would be a great tool for centralized and externalized configuration management in a distributed system. With the configuration microservice you have a central place to manage external properties for applications across all environments. It needs to be accessible via Http with encryption features (and can be decrypted by the client).

Answer (score 3):

Generally centralized config is a bad idea in distributed systems because updating a single value incorrectly (ex: communication certificate) can suddenly cause a distributed failure. This is why Service Fabric specifically recommends that services carry their own configuration (in the Config Package) and that changes to config are versioned and rolled out just like code changes would be. This (usually) prevents a bad config change from affecting the majority of services all at once.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Regarding incorrect values,it can happen as well even to services that carry their own configuration and it can have a cascading failure effect to other services that depends on the service. Spring Cloud Config(https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/)  provides this service for externalized configuration in a distributed system. It can broadcast the config change events to services that subscribes to it. It supports external repositories (eg git) as a storage backend which a webhook can be configured to push notifications.

Comment: I think if architectured and implemented well, a combination of these local config and a centralized config system will be a reliable/durable solution. Just a thought.

Comment: The Service Fabric team has not observed this in practice. The only safe way to deliver configuration changes is to treat them like code changes and to slowly roll them out. Here's just one example of a time that a fast rollout caused an issue. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-on-azure-storage-service-interruption/ It is fine if others want to build and use centralized configuration stores, but again generally we have only seen their use cause trouble and hence will always recommend against building and using them.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion your idea is interesting and correct. Yes there is a recommendation to carry own configuration with each service but I wouldn't do that for all settings. Pick and choose and use your own head. In terms of what you are trying to achieve I've solved this by using Azure Key Vault secrets (this is if you are running in Azure at all). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/about-keys--secrets-and-certificates#BKMK_WorkingWithSecrets for more info on service description. You can version, expire, update and delete secrets which are essentially key-value pairs i.e. settings. In addition to that it is enterpise grade secure and always available.

Now it you want to go further and make it real nice get a strong typed configuration library, for instance https://github.com/aloneguid/config which already has a provider for AKV https://github.com/aloneguid/config/blob/master/doc/Stores_AzureKeyVault.md

Answer (score 0):

There is a project to do exactly this - [Microconfig.IO](https://microconfig.io)
It was designed to manage microservices configuration with dedicated simple templating and has a server to distribute configuration.